# Arraylist insertion sort not working right?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm fairly certain I have the algorithm right and the code is correct but I cannot seem to figure out why it does not sort my numbers correctly.

I'm trying to make an insertion sort program with arraylists but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NewInsertionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <Integer> Array = new ArrayList <Integer>(); 
        Array.add(1);
        Array.add(52);
        Array.add(21);
        Array.add(45);
        Array.add(27); 


        Integer num; 
        Integer lock; 
        Integer num2; 
        for (num2 = 1; num2 < Array.size(); num2++) {
            lock = Array.get(num2 - 1);


            for (num = num2 - 1; (num >= 0) && (Array.get(num) < lock); num--){


                Array.set(num+1, num);

            } 
            lock = Array.get(num+1);  
        }

        for(int z=0;z < Array.size(); z++){
            System.out.println(Array.get(z)); 
        }


    }

}
```

If anyone out there has any advice and aid to give, thank you very much, all help is appreciated.

Comment: `Integer` should be `int`, it should be array instead of `Array`

Comment: @TheProgrammerG But I fixed that and it still just prints the unordered list...

Comment: Use LinkedList instead of ArrayList.

Comment: @eg04lt3r no, don't. Index-based gets and sets in `LinkedList` are `O(n)`; they are `O(1)` in `ArrayList`.

Comment: `Array.set(num+1, num);` is setting the `num+1`-th element to be the value `num`, not the value of the `num`-th element. You might mean `Array.set(num+1, Array.get(num))`.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for that advice, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @HughNotman you've not really stated what the problem is. Please says what the actual output from this code is.

Comment: this line after inner for-loop is an assignment  that never used,check it       `lock = Array.get(num + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On this line you change a value to an index (num):
>
> Array.set(num+1, num);
>
> You probably mean:
>
> Array.set(num+1, Array.get(num));

yes [KompjoeFriek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3931225/kompjoefriek) is right , also you must update i+1 element with lock value , after the end of inner loop

so it must be like this :

```
    Integer num;
    Integer lock;
    Integer num2;

    for (num2 = 1; num2 < Array.size(); num2++) {
        lock = Array.get(num2);

        for (num = num2 - 1; (num >= 0) && (Array.get(num) < lock); num--) {
            Array.set(num + 1, Array.get(num));
        }
        Array.set(num + 1, lock);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you say *"code is correct"* and follow it with *"but I cannot seem to figure out why it does not sort my numbers correctly."* ?

On this line you change a **value** to an **index** (`num`):

```java
Array.set(num+1, num);
```

You probably mean:

```java
Array.set(num+1, Array.get(num));
```

And after that inner-for loop, you never put the value which you stored in `lock` back into the array.

I'm trying to not give you a complete answer, because SO is not here to do your homework for you. Good luck!